# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem' with VueJs

Tags: node.js, webpack, vuejs2

Got this error after adding required development depencencies:

> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem'
>
> Require stack:
>
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/fs.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/index.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem'
>
> Require stack:
>
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/fs.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/index.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
> - /Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
>   at Object. (/Users/nc114/vpsdocs/vps/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/fs.js:7:30)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)

My vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3333'
      }
    },
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    https: false
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  },

  productionSourceMap: false
}
```

my package.js file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.382.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "is-port-reachable": "^2.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.29.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-body-class": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "vue-feather": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-hljs": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.26.1",
    "vue-instantsearch": "^4.0.1",
    "vue-loaders": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-loading-overlay": "^3.1.1",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.5",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.7.1",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "sass": "^1.43.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap-vue": "^0.8.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
```

Comment: did you resolve this? Did you need to install `webpack-cli`? I would love to know.